# How to test a condition for a list and output all the expression that is true?

Tags: function-construction, map

Suppose that I have a list

```
lis={x-y,x+y,x*y};
```

and a function

```
f[a_,b_]:=#/.{x->a,y->b}&
```

I want to output all the one in lis, such that `f[2,2]==4`, how to do this?

I try to do it by

```
Catch[If[f[2, 2] == 4, Throw[#] & /@ lis]]
```

but not work.

---

After a while, I figure it out that I can do this by

```
Catch[If[Evaluate[# /. {x -> 2, y -> 2}] == 4, Throw[#]] & /@ lis]
```

Then the problem is how the get all of the one satisfied? not just the first one.

Comment: This looks like a job for 'Select'!

Comment: It works for me:`Select[lis, Evaluate[# /. {x -> 2, y -> 2}] == 4 &]`, did there any way to write the condition as a function? I mean, in the real case, I have a lot of condtion, such as `#/.{x->2,y->1}==2` and so on...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using the OP's function `f`

```
lis = {x - y, x + y, x*y};

f[a_, b_] := # /. {x -> a, y -> b} &

Map[First, Cases[Map[{#, f[2, 2][#]} &, lis], {_, 4}]]
```

> {x + y, x y}

Alternatively

```
Reap[Map[If[f[2, 2][#] == 4, Sow[#]] &, lis]][[-1, 1]]
```

> {x + y, x y}

Comment: why the output is not clean when I delete `[[-1,1]]` in the alternatively code?

Comment: The first part shows all the output from map.  The sown values are in the last part. See [Reap](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Reap.html)

Comment: ok, it works any way.

Answer (score 1):

```
list = {x - y, x + y, x*y};
```

Using a different test function, that tests for the equality and accepts the equality value as a parameter:

```
testFun[{a_, b_, c_}] := (# /. {x -> a, y -> b}) == c &;
testList = {{2, 2, 4}, {2, 0, 2}};
(* {2, 2, 4} means f[2,2] == 4, and {2, 0, 2} means f[2,0] == 2 *)
```

You can either `Map` over `list`, returning the elements that match any test provided:

```
Select[list, Or @@ Through[(testFun /@ testList)[#]] &]

(* {x - y, x + y, x y} *)
```

Or you can `Map` over `testList`, returning a the elements that matched each of the tests:

```
Function[{currTest}, Select[list, testFun@currTest]] /@ testList

(* {{x + y, x y}, {x - y, x + y}} *)
```

Comment: why the output is not my expected? it should be `x+y` and `x y`

Comment: You mentioned that on the real case you have a lot of conditions, so I've made a list of them -- `testList`. If you look at the last line of the answer, you will see that the first element is indeed `{x + y, x y}`, which corresponds to the first condition of `testList`, `{2,2,4}` (representing the test `f[2,2] == 4`). If you want to test more conditions, just add mode triples to `testList`, in the form `{a,b,c}` (representing `f[a,b] == c`)

Answer (score 1):

You can use `Select` if you are willing to modify your function slightly:

```
Select[lis, (Function[{x, y}, #][2, 2] == 4) &]

(*{x + y, x y}*)
```