# How to use nest to reduce the memory eatting of mma?

Tags: memory, iterators

I enconter a problem about number:

> If we have
>
> 5+3+2=151022
>
> 9+2+4=183652
>
> 8+6+3=482466
>
> 5+4+5=202541
>
> then 7+2+5=?

It is easy to get the first two group of numbers? for the last, it is not so easy to observe, what's more, it is even harder to show that the answer is uniqe in some sense.

So I just work it out with mma:

```
var = {x, y, z};
biop[x_, y_] := {x + y, x - y, x*y}
lis[0] = var;
op[0] = var;
lis[n_] := 
 Union[Subsets[op[n - 1], {2}], 
  First[Table[{i, j}, {i, var}, {j, op[n - 1]}]]]
op[n_] := 
 Union[Flatten[
   Table[ExpandAll[biop[#1, #2]] & @@ elem, {elem, lis[n]}]]]
f[a_, b_, c_] := # /. {x -> a, y -> b, z -> c} &
Reap[Map[If[
     f[5, 3, 2][#] == 22 && f[9, 2, 4][#] == 52 && 
      f[8, 6, 3][#] == 66 && f[5, 4, 5][#] == 41, Sow[#]] &, 
   op[3]]][[-1, 1]]
```

Let me explain the code a litter. Firstly we define three variables and a function `f`, which represent `5+3+2=22` as `x+y+z=f[5,3,2]=22`. Then we construct all the bineary-operator I need as in `biop` (I didn't consider `x/y`). Next, we encounter the situation of construcing all possiable ways of combine `x,y,z` with the bineary operator.

To do this, I first define a function `lis[n]`, which will give all the pairs of elements, that will be applied to the `biop`, here `n` represens the number of `biop`.  In case the list is constructed, the possiable expression which contain `n` `biop` is easy to get by apply `biop` to `op[n-1]`.

The last `reap` function is to output all the expression that satisfies the condition of the question. In fact, I just copy it from the older post [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/66627/how-to-test-a-condition-for-a-list-and-output-all-the-expression-that-is-true/66631?noredirect=1#comment186219_66631).

Now, my problem is that, when I try to get all the possibility 4 combination of `biop` satisfies the condition, mma tell me that `The current computation was aborted because there was insufficient memory available to complete the computation.` But my ram is only used 50% of 2G.

I think we can work this without list all the possibal combination, and verify it as soon as I get the expression of `biop`. But How?

Comment: `Let me explain the code a litter` sounds like a confession:)

Comment: 7+2+5=143547  (mah brain faster than mma)

Comment: @belisarius your mean my grammar is wrong?

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Litter

Comment: hah, I see. It should be a little.